# Laravel 5.3 to 5.4 upgrade issue since Blade::setRawTags(), Blade::setContentTags() and Blade::setEscapedContentTags() were removed

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my app from laravel 5.3 to 5.4.
Unfortunately according to the laravel api documentation ( https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html ) it seems like the functions Blade::setRawTags(), Blade::setContentTags() and Blade::setEscapedContentTags() were removed. 
This is an issue for me since I had to use these functions to make my laravel 4.2 syntax laravel 5 compatible(This was also the way described in the upgrade guide from 4.2 to 5.0).
This prevents composer install/composer update from running as it will return, that it could not find the function.
Also I was not able to find out why they were removed or what a solution for this problem would be.
Do any of you know any alternative methods or a way to make this work, without changing my whole syntax?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your best bet is probably to extend the BladeCompiler class, override the tags as required, and then to bind the class/interface in `bootstrap/app.php`. What do you need to change the tags from/to?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution sounds plausible. I needed to i.e. change tags from {!! !!} to {{ }}. However I decided to now change the syntax everywhere in the code so the app is up to the newest standard and is not fixed with quickfixes everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

in your App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php change:

```
public function register(){
       \Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
        \Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
        \Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
}
```

to

```
public function register(){
//empty
}
```

Then try running composer update again.